# Unknown operation in derivation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I was trying to find the derivative of $\sqrt{1-\dfrac {v^2(t)}{c^2}}$ and when I checked on Symbola I found [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/first-derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(sqrt%5Cleft(1-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7Bc%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright)%5Cright)/?origin=enterkey).

I don't understand how they "simplify" at the end, the last step. How they get to $\frac{-x}{\sqrt{c^2-x^2}}$. Could anyone clarify this to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2}(c^2-v^2)}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{|c|}\sqrt{c^2-v^2}} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2-v^2}}$$

Does that help?

Comment: How did you do the last step please ?

Comment: @ArthurRimbaud: $${1\over \frac 1c}=\frac cc\cdot{1\over \frac 1c}={c\over \frac cc}=\frac c1 = c$$

Comment: Do you understand now @ArthurRimbaud?

Comment: Thanks, I understand! But is that step really necessary? I mean I could just write the derivative without simplifying and it would still be correct, right?

Comment: Sure.  Simplifying in general just makes an expression a little easier to understand and work with.  But it's by no means necessary.